# Custom Ui Columns In A Box

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I want to put columns in a box, apparently I don't know how I can do this.
I have got the following code:

```
        split = layout.split(factor = 0.75)
        col = split.column(align = True)
        
        col.label(text = "select your armor here", icon = "OUTLINER_OB_ARMATURE")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorHelmetEnum", text = "Helmet")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorChestplateEnum", text = "Chestplate")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorLeggingsEnum", text = "Leggings")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorBootsEnum", text = "Boots") 
        
        col = split.column(align = True)
        col.label(text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "helmet_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "chestplate_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "leggings_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "boots_color", text = "")
```

[image]

It's not in the Box as I would like it to be. I googled it but I haven't found a good answer that has helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert the Box component before the split.

````
        box = layout.box()
        split = box.split(factor = 0.75)
        col = split.column(align = True)
        
        col.label(text = "select your armor here", icon = "OUTLINER_OB_ARMATURE")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorHelmetEnum", text = "Helmet")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorChestplateEnum", text = "Chestplate")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorLeggingsEnum", text = "Leggings")
        col.prop(obj, "ArmorBootsEnum", text = "Boots") 
        
        col = split.column(align = True)
        col.label(text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "helmet_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "chestplate_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "leggings_color", text = "")
        col.prop(obj, "boots_color", text = "")
```
````